# PDO execute() statement with placeholder in LIMIT

Tags: php, sql

```
$pageMin = (($page * 10)-10);

$reponse = $bdd->prepare('SELECT pseudo, message FROM minichat ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?, 10');
$reponse->execute(array($pageMin));
```

It seems like the placeholders don't work for LIMIT...

When I concatenate with pageMin it works, ex:

```
$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT pseudo, message FROM minichat ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT' . $pageMin . ', 10');
```

or even

```
$reponse = $bdd->prepare('SELECT pseudo, message FROM minichat ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT' . $pageMin . ', 10');
$reponse->execute(array());
```

Using the placeholder, it does not return me any results, why?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: I'm not sure about the real question, but wouldn't `LIMIT' . $pageMin . '`, if `$pageMin` was, say, '5', evaluate to `LIMIT5` (no space)?  Try making it `LIMIT '.$pageMin.'`

Comment: It's just a typing error, it works when I concatenate, my problem is when I want to use placeholders ex: LIMITE ?, 10, then it does not work.

Comment: I don't get any error, but my results are not good (just no results)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass an array of params to `execute` they are treated as strings and limit is an int. Just use bindValue with type int.

```
$reponse->bindValue(1, $pageMin, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: Thanks, but what is the 1 for? In your example

Comment: Ahh I found out, it's for the first placeholder.