# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE Syntax error or access violation

Tags: php, sql, select

i get this error, when i use select

```
$listchat = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM listchat WHERE ?, userkey=?, ORDER BY idroom ASC LIMIT ?");
```

then

```
$num = 10;
$gid = 0;
$listchat->execute([$gid,$userKey,$num]);
```

I get the post title error, where am I wrong?

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' userkey='66756',

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the column to compare with `$gid`. And conditions are combined using `AND` or `OR`, not commas.

```
$listchat = $pdo->prepare("
    SELECT * 
    FROM listchat 
    WHERE gid = ? AND userkey=? 
    ORDER BY idroom ASC 
    LIMIT ?");
```

You also need to use `bindParam` or `bindValue` to supply a value for `LIMIT`, so you can specify that it should be treated as an integer, not a string.

```
$listchat->bindValue(1, $gid);
$listchat->bindValue(2, $userKey);
$listchat->bindValue(3, $num, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$listchat->execute();
```

Comment: I did as you wrote $listchat = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM listchat WHERE idroom > ? ABD userkey=? ORDER BY idroom ASC LIMIT ?");
but I always get the error

Comment: Is the `ABD` typo in the real code or a copying error?

Comment: Don't change the question to match the answer, how will other readers know what problem I was solving? I've reverted your edit.

Comment: Are you still getting the same error or a different error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868079/pdo-execute-statement-with-placeholder-in-limit